# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I will post code that I think is important, if you need something more tell me. I have hibernate in project structure/facets. If I also need to post my `pom.xml` I will. What m I missing, is my config for App bad? How I can solve this? Did I put bad package to scan on session factory variable?

`DemoAppConfig class:`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("ets")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-mysql.properties")
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource securityDataSource() {
        
        // create connection pool
        ComboPooledDataSource securityDataSource
                                    = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        
        try {
            securityDataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
        } catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
        
        logger.info(">>> jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info(">>> jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));

        securityDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        securityDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        securityDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        
        securityDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(
                getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));

        securityDataSource.setMinPoolSize(
                getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));

        securityDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(
                getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));

        securityDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(
                getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));
        
        return securityDataSource;
    }

    
    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {
        
        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);
        
        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);
        
        return intPropVal;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(securityDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"ets.entity"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

---

`EmployeeController class`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listEmployee(Model theModel) {

        // get customers from the service
        List<Employee> theEmployee = employeeService.listEmployee();

        // add the customers to the model
        theModel.addAttribute("employees", theEmployee);

        return "list-employee";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showFormForAdd")
    public String showFormForAdd(Model theModel) {

        // create model attribute to bind form data
        Employee theEmployee = new Employee();

        theModel.addAttribute("employee", theEmployee);

        return "addNewEmployeeForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addNewEmployee")
    public String addNewEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee theEmployee) {

        // save the customer using our service
        employeeService.addNewEmployee(theEmployee);


        return "redirect:/employee/list";
    }
}
```

---

`EmployeeDAO class:`

```
    @Repository
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

....
```

---

`EmployeeServiceImpl class:`

```
    @Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

....
```

---

Entity `Employee:`

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_detail_id")
    private EmployeeDetail employeeDetail;
```

---

Entity `EmployeeDetail:`

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "employee_detail")
public class EmployeeDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="work_experience")
    private int workExperience;

    @Column(name="hobby")
    private int hobby;

    @Column(name="language")
    private int language;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee")
private Employee employee;
```

`Stack trace:`

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ets.config.DemoAppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: ets.entity.EmployeeDetail.employee, referenced property unknown: ets.entity.Employee.employee
```

---

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ets.config.DemoAppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: ets.entity.EmployeeDetail.employee, referenced property unknown: ets.entity.Employee.employee
```

---

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ets.config.DemoAppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: ets.entity.EmployeeDetail.employee, referenced property unknown: ets.entity.Employee.employee
```

---

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ets.config.DemoAppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: ets.entity.EmployeeDetail.employee, referenced property unknown: ets.entity.Employee.employee
```

---

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: ets.entity.EmployeeDetail.employee, referenced property unknown: ets.entity.Employee.employee
at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:169)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1684)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1652)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
```

---

And same `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` for `employeeController`, `employeeServiceImpl`, `employeeDAOImpl` and etc.

Comment: Can you please set the pom.xml dependency and the import of annotation @repository  because they should be from JPA

Answer (score 0):

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "employeeDetail")
private Employee employee;

Answer (score -1):

Use
`@ComponentScan`

instead of

`@ComponentScan("ets")`

but if you want the specific path to scan then you give a complete path not just 'ets' as you give in
`@ComponentScan("com.example.ets")`

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning and this article helpful for you

Comment: After I changed that I got just 3 errors
`Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ets.config.DemoAppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: ets.entity.EmployeeDetail.employee`

---

`Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ets.config.DemoAppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: ets.entity.EmployeeDetail.employee` 

And same for session factory

Comment: employee_detail_id  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee_detail_id  ")
private Employee employee; try change to this

Comment: @StefanJankovic In EmployeeDetail you should mappedBy = "employee_detail_id"

Comment: @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(securityDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"ets.entity"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

Comment: @StefanJankovic  above i mention  sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"ets.entity"}); in which give you base Component Scan like you did above example i give

Comment: was you cahnge sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan( new String[]{"ets.entity"}); change ets.entity to base component . what you change there before ?

Comment: Is mappedBy = “employeeDetail”